# I created a PrintWriter with autoflush on; why isn't it autoflushing?

Tags: java, io, flush, printwriter

My client is a web browser, and sending request to myserver using this url:
**`http://localhost`**

This is the server side code. The problem lies in the run method of the `ServingThread` class.

```
class ServingThread implements Runnable{
    private Socket socket ;

    public ServingThread(Socket socket){
        this.socket = socket ;
        System.out.println("Receives a new browser request from "
                      + socket + "\n\n");
    }

    public void run() {
        PrintWriter out = null ;

        try {
            String str = "" ;
            out = new PrintWriter( socket.getOutputStream() ) ;
            out.write("This a web-page.") ;
            // :-(
            out.flush() ;
            // :-(
            socket.close() ;
            System.out.println("Request successfully fulfilled.") ;
        } catch (IOException io) {
            System.out.println(io.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Whether I am using

```
out = new PrintWriter( socket.getOutputStream(), true ) ;
```

or

```
out = new PrintWriter( socket.getOutputStream() ) ;
```

the output is not coming to the browser.
Output is coming to the browser only if I am manually flushing using stream using

```
out.flush() ;
```

**My question:** `new PrintWriter( socket.getOutputStream(), true )` is supposed to automatically flush the output buffer, but it's not doing so. Why?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

From the [Javadocs](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter(java.io.OutputStream,%20boolean)):

> #### Parameters:
>
> `out` - An output stream
> `autoFlush` - A boolean; if true, the `println`, `printf`, or `format` methods will flush the output buffer

It does not say that `write()` will flush the output buffer. Try using `println()` instead and it should flush like you expect it to.

Comment: Its a horrible implementation! Setting autoFlush on a printWriter does not result in it autoFlushing!.

Comment: From my tests, I can confirm that write and print methods are not autoflushed, hence you must manually call the flush method by the end of your program/execution when you'll using any of those methods. Otherwise you'll get no output or a truncated output (because it flushes when the internal buffer is full anyway).