# PrintWriter autoflush puzzling logic

Tags: java, io, printwriter, printstream, autoflush

[public PrintWriter(OutputStream out, boolean autoFlush)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter%28java.io.OutputStream,%20boolean%29):

> ```
> out - An output stream
> autoFlush - A boolean; if true, the println, printf, or format methods
> will flush the output buffer
> ```

[public PrintStream(OutputStream out, boolean autoFlush)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#PrintStream%28java.io.OutputStream,%20boolean%29):

> ```
> out - The output stream to which values and objects will be printed 
> autoFlush - A boolean; if true, the output buffer will be flushed 
> whenever a byte array is written, one of the println methods is invoked, 
> or a newline character or byte ('\n') is written
> ```

#### What was the reason for changing autoflush logic between these classes?

Because they are always considered as identical except for encoding moments and "autoflush" without flushing on `print()` hardly corresponds to principle of least astonishment, silly bugs occur:
[I created a PrintWriter with autoflush on; why isn't it autoflushing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240968/i-created-a-printwriter-with-autoflush-on-why-isnt-it-autoflushing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer lies in the history of Java. The trio `InputStream`, `OutputStream` and `PrintStream` in `java.io` date back to Java 1.0. That is before serious support for file encodings and character sets were built into the language.

To quote the Javadoc:

> "A PrintStream adds functionality to
>   another output stream, namely the
>   ability to print representations of
>   various data values conveniently. Two
>   other features are provided as well.
>   Unlike other output streams, a
>   PrintStream never throws an
>   IOException; instead, exceptional
>   situations merely set an internal flag
>   that can be tested via the checkError
>   method..."

To summarize, it is a convenience for generating textual output, grafted on top of lower level IO.

In Java 1.1, `Reader`, `Writer` and `PrintWriter` were introduced. Those all support character sets. While `InputStream` and `OutputStream` still had a real uses (raw data processing), `PrintStream` became far less relevant, because printing by nature is about text.

The Javadoc for `PrintWriter` explicitly states:

> Unlike the PrintStream class, if
>   automatic flushing is enabled it will
>   be done only when one of the println()
>   methods is invoked, rather than
>   whenever a newline character happens
>   to be output. The println() methods
>   use the platform's own notion of line
>   separator rather than the newline
>   character.

Put another way, PrintWriter should only be used through the `print*(...)` APIs, because writing newline characters etc should not be the caller's responsibility, the same way dealing with file encodings and character sets are not the caller's responsibility.

I would argue that `PrintWriter` should have been `java.io.Printer` instead, and not have extended `Writer`. I don't know whether they extended to mimic `PrintStream`, or because they were stuck on maintaining the pipe design idiom.

Comment: Thanks you, the logic is cleared a bit. But i should mention that have caught a problem while using socket API, where '\r\n' line separator is specified in RFC documents, so `println()` is unacceptable.

Comment: If the RFC cares about line endings, etc, then you need to be working with InputStreams and OutputStreams. Using PrintStreams or PrintWriters for implementing a socket-level RFC is dangerous. However, the RFC may still adopt UTF or a similar character encoding. If it does, you should use APIs like String.getBytes(...) and CharsetEncoder on a line-by-line basis, but still manage the stream without the 'printing' abstractions.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it wasn't the same at start was probably just an accident. Now it's backwards compatibility.

Comment: Welcome to the real world. Hope you enjoy, goodbye. j/k. I can't be sure, of course, but what else?